# How to keep views aligned inside ReativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-relativelayout

The below posted `xml` layout is a lyout of a `listView`, the `editText` allows the user to enter a string, and the `imageView` is an clickable icon when pressed, the string should be added to the `listView`.

The views are aligned to each other as shown below in the `xml`. The problem is when the user enters a very short string or a long string then clicks the icon to add it to the `listview`, what happens is I lose the alignment of the `CheckBox` and `imageView`.

For example, initially the `listview` is aligned as follows, where `CB` refers to `CheckBox` and `iv` refers to `Imageview`, and the dots indicate the spaces separating the views:

```
topic_1..........CB..........IV

topic_2..........CB..........IV

topic_3..........CB..........IV

topic_4..........CB..........IV

topic_5..........CB..........IV

topic_6..........CB..........IV

topic_10000..........CB..........IV

t..........CB..........IV
```

As you can see, in "topic_10000" and in "t", the position of both of `CB` and `IV` is displaced. But I want the `checkBox` and the `imageview` to be always aligned under each other no matter what the length of the topic is.

How can I achieve this?

**xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rl1_List"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvlist_topic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rl2_List"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/rl1_List"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="70dp">
    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/cbList_hook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:checked="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rl3_List"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/rl2_List"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/ivList_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/delete_icon"
        android:contentDescription="icon to delete item from the Listview"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstCBId"
```

On all your CB but the first one.

Also, you shouldn't use all those nested `RelativeLayout`: just one is sufficient. You can then use `android:layout_below` for vertical spacing.

Comment: There are some examples here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: i think you mean t call android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstCBId" in each imageView?right?

Comment: Nope, I do mean in the CheckBoxes. `layout_alignLeft` means you align this view's left border with the other one's. Then you also need to account for the vertical alignment, for which layout_below should be use.

Answer (score 0):

you can use linearlayout instead of using relativelayout and apply weightsum. In below example i have applied same weight to all 3 views. You can set it as per your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="6" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvlist_topic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbList_hook"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:checked="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivList_delete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="icon to delete item from the Listview"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the lenth of text is variable, you can set fixed lenght to the textView's Relativelayout, then place the relativeLayout of the second View "checkBox" to the end of the relativeLayout of the textView, then for the last relativeLayout 2the one of the Imageview" you can specify marginStart.

so you can manipulate the width of the `android:id="@+id/rl1_List"`

Below is the interpretation of the the above text.

**xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rl1_List"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvlist_topic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rl2_List"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/rl1_List"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbList_hook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:checked="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rl3_List"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/rl2_List"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/ivList_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/delete_icon"
        android:contentDescription="icon to delete item from the Listview"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by using LinearLayout rather than RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text1"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: LinearLayout]

If you want to use only Relative layout then go with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:padding="20sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text1"/>
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:padding="20sp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: RelativeImage]